# Push Notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I followed this tutorial to implement push , in my iOS app , [Apple Push Notification Services Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)

I did everything as stated and the push notifications work great. However , i dont see my app in the settings menu , so that i can be able to disable the push notifications if i like.

All i added to my code was :

In the delegate.m file :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    return YES;
}
```

and

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

All i want is to be able to disable the push notifications. The tutorial states that i should have this options with the code above , but i dont see anything.

Comment: Does your application's provisioning profile have push notification support enabled?

Comment: of course. I said that the push works great. I just dont know how to disable it. I see nothing on the settings menu. When i start the app , it asks me if i want to use push , and i get all the push correctly. Is there a method i must implement to have this option on the settings? Shouldnt it be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you checking in the right place? The right place is under Settings -> Notifications. The app does not appear in Settings list directly unless you actually have settings configured (and even when it does, the notification settings do not appear there).

Comment: Yes you are completely right. The tutorial said on settings , and i had all the apps there so i couldnt see mine and thought something was wrong. But the app is where you say. One more question if you know. I want to be able to see from my server if the user has the push enabled. Is this possible? When he enables/disables push , do i have access to this variable , so that i can send it to my server and see if my users have them enabled or disabled?

Comment: People may turn on and off push for your app at any time and you have no idea whether alerts are shown as alerts or banners. This is why you have to talk to the APNS feedback service to know when to stop sending notifications. You can have a good approximation by making calls to your own server from didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError, as well as keeping the results from the feedback service in mind.

Comment: Additionally, to even send the notifications in the first place, you need to send the push identifier to your server and associate it with the user or device in your backend somehow. See [the programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more details on this flow.